# Recriar pasta Android projeto Flutter

Tags: flutter

Qual comando utilizo para recriar a pasta Android do meu projeto Flutter?

Ao tentar Flutter build apk, a IDE me retornou o erro abaixo

[!] Your app is using an unsupported Gradle project. To fix this problem, create a new project by running `flutter create -t app <app-directory>` and then move the dart code, assets and pubspec.yaml to the new project.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Dentro da pasta do projeto, execute no terminal:

```
flutter create .
```

o `.` nesse caso está referenciando a pasta atual, então ele vai recriar os arquivos ali dentro.

Comment: Funcionou. Porem, o nome do diretório do projeto não pode conter espaços e nem letras maiúsculas.